# Larave Vue post request return 500 internal server error

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, api, vue.js

I'm just getting into laravel and don't have any knowledge of vuejs either i have a very simple code that is trying to send to the server a request and the server should return an alert with username on it here is my code.

blade.php

```
<button user-id="{{ $user->id }}"></button>
```

vue compenent

```
<template>
 <div>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="action">Follow</a>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default{
    props: [userId],
    mounted(){
      console.log('Component mounted.')
    },
    methods:{
      action(){
        axious.post('/follow/' + this.userId)
          .then( response => {
            alter( response.data )
          })
      } 
    }
  }
</script>
```

php code

route

```
Route::post('/follow/{user}', [ProfileController::class, 'store'];
```

Profile controller class

```
public function store(User $user){
  return $user->username;
}
```

error

```
app.js:285 POST http://localhost:8000/follow/2 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ app.js:285
xhrAdapter @ app.js:119
dispatchRequest @ app.js:765
Promise.then (async)
request @ app.js:542
Axios.<computed> @ app.js:567
wrap @ app.js:1131
followUser @ app.js:1924
invokeWithErrorHandling @ app.js:39512
invoker @ app.js:39837
original._wrapper @ app.js:45196
app.js:699 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (app.js:699)
    at settle (app.js:960)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:168)
```

Comment: check the error logs to see why you are getting a 500

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message. For Laravel, also look in `storage/logs`

Comment: in the storage/logs folder there is only laravel.log file with over 10000+ lines of comments

Comment: Those are very important comments when troubleshooting 500 errors. You can rename that file and try again to start off with a clean file. I'd also suggest [changing your logging to daily](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging) to keep log files from getting too large.

Comment: Click on the network tab and then on the XHR tab. Try looking for the file and click on it.

Comment: when a open network tab and click on the file that shows on red it point to this line

request.send(requestData);

on the file app.js.

Comment: in the log i get this error `local.ERROR: Target class [App\Http\Controllers\User] does not exist. {"userId":1,"exception":"[object]                                                                       (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target class [App\\Http\\Controllers\\User] does not exist. at /home/cryptomasdar/Development/Back-end/Laravel/             Instagram/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:811)
`

Comment: You need to use the full namespace for `User` in your controller, or add it as a `use` statement at the top

Comment: Thank you i just found it out.

Answer (score 1):

Next time when you dealing with api request and had an error like this just switch to the network tap on developers tools and track your request then click on response you can find the entire exception trace.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the error i was not importing the class User in the ProfileController class.

Thank you all for your quick response.